# Ignore <br> with CSS?

Tags: css

I'm working on a site which has line breaks inserted as `<br>` in some of the headings. Assuming I can't edit the source HTML, is there a way with CSS I can ignore these breaks?

I'm mobile optimising the site so I don't really want to use JavaScript.

Comment: @Ben Johnson mk2: The answer to your question:"I would like a solution to @Aneesh Karthik C's answer for firefox and opera" is, that it is not possible with the use of `br` elements! The reasons are already explained numerous times! In my answer I showed you an alternative method to achieve the goal in valid, robust and cross browser way.

Answer (score 231, accepted):

With css, you can "hide" the br tags and they won't have an effect:

```
br {
    display: none;
}
```

If you only want to hide some within a specific heading type, just make your css more specific.

```
h3 br {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Make sure to take a look at Aneesh's answer too, it is relevant and fixes an issue that enobrev didn't consider in his.

Comment: Agreed, Aneesh's answer is a fantastic addition.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18040142/14651

Comment: This solution does not work for Firefox. If the <br/> does not have space around it then it combines words around <br/> together. Here is the [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/P6NZd/28/) You can see discussion about it [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21754314/1412655)

Comment: If your goal is responsive design, the only cross-browser solution is @Netsurfer's. It doesn't answer the question exactly as stated, but it  does achieve the goal in all modern browsers.

Answer (score 109):

**Note: This solution only works for Webkit browsers, which incorrectly apply pseudo-elements to self-closing tags.**

As an addendum to above answers it is worth noting that in some cases one needs to insert a space instead of merely ignoring `<br>`:

For instance the above answers will turn

```
Monday<br>05 August
```

to

```
Monday05 August
```

as I had verified while I tried to format my weekly event calendar. A space after "Monday" is preferred to be inserted. This can be done easily by inserting the following in the CSS:

```
br  {
    content: ' '
}
br:after {
    content: ' '
}
```

This will make

```
Monday<br>05 August
```

look like

```
Monday 05 August
```

You can change the `content` attribute in `br:after` to `', '` if you want to separate by commas, or put anything you want within `' '` to make it the delimiter! By the way

```
Monday, 05 August
```

looks neat ;-)

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nicooprat/ZHxNA/) for a reference.

As in the above answers, if you want to make it tag-specific, you can. As in if you want this property to work for tag `<h3>`, just add a `h3` each before `br` and `br:after`, for instance.

It works most generally for a pseudo-tag.

Comment: so very very genius !

Comment: Well done, actually thinking about the consequences of simply disabling it!

Comment: "disabling" I assume meaning what the other answers have done, `display:none`. Excellent points made by the way, and good solution to a strange problem.

Comment: Good point but this seems to work only with Webkit browsers (Chrome & Safari) with Firefox and IE this technique doesn't work, check the http://jsfiddle.net/nicooprat/ZHxNA/ with Firefox and IE... any ideas how to replace a br with a space so that it works with all main braowsers?

Comment: @firepol: Actually, Firefox and IE are doing things "correct" as a `<br />` is one [element that a pseudo-element is not supposed to work on](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pseudo-element/info). And `content` only works on pseudo-elements.

Comment: Oh strange. It actually works in Firefox 26.0 in my Precise Pangolin machine. I could control elements. Opera I still have to check.

Comment: This is very wrong solution, mainly bcause of what @ScottS already wrote. "Content" is supposed to work only with pseudo-elements, and pseudo-element aren't supposed to work with self closing tags. This may work for now, but I wouldn't dare to call this solution future-proof.

Comment: @Mr_Green: Have you read the comment above yours (the one from nd_macias)!?

Comment: I just checked, it does not work on Safari 16.

Answer (score 17):

If you add in the style

```
br{
    display: none;
}
```

Then this will work. Not sure if it will work in older versions of IE though.

Comment: this was posted earlier and have less votes.. how come?

Comment: Sometimes, we just get ignored ;(

Comment: @TimBJames it does not work in FIREFOX you can check my detailed comment [above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596647/ignore-br-with-css?answertab=active#comment33033165_7596709)

Answer (score 13):

This is how I do it:

```
br { 
    display: inline;
    content: ' ';
    clear:none;
}
```

Comment: It won't work on Safari 16 on MacOS, I've just tried. I'm about to give up and replace `br` with `span` from Netsurfer's suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `span` elements instead of the `br` if you want the white space method to work, as it depends on pseudo-elements which are "not defined" for replaced elements.

**HTML**

```
<p>
   To break lines<span class="line-break">in a paragraph,</span><span>don't use</span><span>the 'br' element.</span>
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
span {white-space: pre;}

span:after {content: ' ';}

span.line-break {display: block;}

span.line-break:after {content: none;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHxNA/249/)

The line break is simply achieved by setting the appropriate span element to `display:block`.

By using IDs and/ or Classes in your HTML markup you can easily target every single or combination of span elements by CSS or use CSS selectors like `nth-child()`.

So you can e.g. define different break points by using media queries for a responsive layout.

And you can also simply add/ remove/ toggle classes by Javascript (jQuery).

The "advantage" of this method is its robustness - works in every browser that supports pseudo-elements (see: [Can I use - CSS Generated content](http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent)).

As an alternative it is also possible to add a line break via pseudo-elements:

```
span.break:before {  
    content: "\A";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ub2TJ/1/)

Comment: Did you miss this part of the question: "Assuming I cant edit the source html"?

Comment: @ScottS: No, I did not. Maybe you missed the part:'I would like a solution to @Aneesh Karthik C's answer for firefox and opera' (as the one who started the bounty is not the OP). And the answer to this is, that it is not possible with `<br>`, at least not cross-browser. So I showed an alternative.

Comment: No, I did not miss that part (that OP is different from bounty and the focus on Aneesh's answer). But Aneesh's answer is in the context of the whole question, to "Ignore <br> with CSS?" It seems rather obvious that if one has actual control of the html, then simply _deleting_ the `<br>` elements solves the issue (presumably replacing them with spaces). So the whole issue with which the question as a whole is concerned about is when one _does not have control of the html_; complicated by the added stipulation that they really did not want to use javascript (for whatever reason) to solve it.

Comment: The question "How to ignore `<br>` with CSS?" was already answered. And only if you are in control of the HTML that doesn't mean, that you want to change it. But in responsive design it is often desirable to be in control of line breaks (other than the automatic wrap). And in such cases the method of having white space or not controled by CSS (media queries) is at least "one method" to achieve the goal.

Comment: This worked better for me now that the above solutions no longer work in firefox.

Answer (score 2):

For me looks better like this:

`Some text,  Some text,  Some text`

```css
br {
  display: inline;
  content: '';
}

br:after {
  content: ', ';
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:block">
  <span>Some text</span>
  <br>
  <span>Some text</span>
  <br>
  <span>Some text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For that you can just do like this:

```
br{display: none;}
```

and if it is inside some PRE tag, then you can and if you want the PRE tag to behave like a regular block element, you can use this CSS :

```
pre {white-space: normal;}
```

Or you can follow the style of [Aneesh Karthik C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2404407/aneesh-karthik-c)
like :

```
br  {content: ' '}
br:after {content: ' '}
```

I think you got it

Comment: I think you missed the point that pseudo-elements like `::before` and `::after` are at least "undefined" for "replaced elements" like `br`. So there will never be a consistent browser behaviour one can rely on! The only thing you can do, is to **not use pseudo elements** with these elements!

Answer (score 1):

As per your question, to solve this problem for Firefox and Opera using [Aneesh Karthik C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18040142/14651) approach you need to add "float" right" attribute.

Check the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/P6NZd/20/) here. This CSS works in
Firefox (26.0) , Opera (12.15), Chrome (32.0.1700) and Safari (7.0)

```
br {
   content: " ";  
   float:right; 
}
```

I hope this will answer your question!!

Comment: The content property only has effect on CSS pseudo elements. So it is absolutely useless in your demo! And how to "neutralize" a `br` is already answered (more than once). The question is about **conditional white space**. And as this requires the use of pseudo elements, **it does not work with `br`**.

Comment: If you read the question carefully. You will understand the answer. I have seen the answer above that is the best to avoid <br> by just setting it to display:none. But as per the second question where he wants to find out how he can address issue that is coming in FF and Opera for Aneesh solution.

Comment: I have read not only the question but also all answers and comments very carefully. Content property for `br` is simply nonsense! And I still cannot see what the rest of your answer has to do with "conditional white space and line brekas"? Maybe you can explain it further more, please?

Comment: Your example is misleading, as you have spaces already around the `br` elements. [If you remove those, you will see it is not working to add any space.](http://jsfiddle.net/P6NZd/21/)

Comment: @ScottS I am not really clear what space are you talking about I do not see any space around my <br> element. And if you are talking about (Content: " ") then that is because I was referring exactly what is mentioned in Aneesh's post

Comment: In your example you have three `br` elements, with spaces before and after the first and last one. It is those spaces that make it appear that your solution is working, when in fact it is not. When you remove those spaces, as I did in my revised example, you can see that your solution is not adding any space at all in Firefox.

Comment: I agree with you @ScottS and If you try the above [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7596709/1412655) in that case also it will not work. as content property of <br> in Firefox does not work at all and when we do float:right it just join the first and second word.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the point of why the bounty was set. The person was hoping someone had a solution that could work around that. Aneesh's answer only worked on webkit browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply convert it in a comment..

Or you can do this:

```
br {
display: none;
}
```

But if you do not want it why are you puting that there?

Comment: in some cases it's useful to hide them for specific media queries. A linebreak might make sense at a wider screen size, but not at a narrower one.

Answer (score 0):

While this question appears to already have been solved, the accepted answer didn't solve the problem for me on Firefox.
Firefox (and possibly IE, though I haven't tried it) skip whitespaces while reading the contents of the "content" tag. While I completely understand why Mozilla would do that, it does bring its share of problems.
The easiest workaround I found was to use non-breakable spaces instead of regular ones as shown below.

```
.noLineBreaks br:before{
content: '\a0'
}
```

[Have a look](http://jsfiddle.net/3HWH6/1/).

Comment: Why does your fiddle not have the `before` element on a `br`? You don't even have a `br` in your html on the fiddle. Part of the issue is that `before` does not work on a `br` in some browsers.

Comment: That is quite expected behaviour, as stated in the spec: [2.5.1 Common parser idioms](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/common-microsyntaxes.html#space-character)

Comment: Tha's certainly weird, it works when I apply it in my project. My text isn't all HTML, though, the content I'm altering comes from a database.
Sorry my anwser didn't help, then.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can ignore this `<br>`.
You may need this especially in case of responsive design where you need to remove breaks for mobile devices.

HTML

```
<h2>

  Where ever you go <br class="break"> i am there.

</h2>
```

CSS for mobile example

```
/* Resize the browser window to check */

@media (max-width: 640px) 
{
  .break {display: none;}
}
```

Check out this Codepen:
https://codepen.io/fluidbrush/pen/pojGQyM

Answer (score 0):

You can use`display:contents`

```css
br {
  display:contents;
}
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display-box

> [display:contents;] These elements don't produce a specific box by themselves. They are replaced by their pseudo-box and their child boxes [...] most browsers will remove from the accessibility tree any element with a display value of contents. [...] no longer be announced by screen reading technology.

Comment: as of 2022 browser still partially supports display:contents

Comment: @Nivethan, yes partialy but supported. No problems related to this use case. 
It works.