# stop BR tag breaking with CSS

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to stop a `<br>` tag breaking using only CSS?

I tried `br{display:none}` whick works, but it also gets rid of the space between the two words, which I need to keep.

This is only for webkit (iPhone) so any CSS3 extravaganza is just fine.

I can't edit the content from the CMS, so simply removing the tag unfortunately isn't an option for me.

thanks!

Comment: space between 2 words? How is `<br />` inserting space between words? Or did you mean linebreaks?

Comment: Is Javascript a possibility? That would be trivial...

Comment: What I mean is the `<br>` needs to become the space. If the HTML is `<p>hello<br/>there</p>` then `br{display:none}` stops there being a space between the two words

Comment: Sadly I can't use Javascript here ... the only weapon I have is a static CSS file

Comment: ah, then try this:
`br {display: inline-block; margin-right: 5px; }`.

Comment: This isn't possible to do. The only way to 'remove' a `<br/>` with css is to `display: none` it. That means that you then can't use the `:before` / `:after` pseudo-selectors to try and add content (a non breaking space) into the html. http://jsfiddle.net/NrcFL/

Comment: @xFortyFourx Doesn't seem to work... http://jsfiddle.net/JFkDy/

Comment: I tested lots of combinations of styles, but the only thing that I found works is to replace the `br` element with a space through a script, like Basic says. Or, make sure you have some whitespace around the `<br>` (e.g. a CRLF after each) so you can do `display:none`.

Comment: The curious pattern of pre-emptively rejecting the solution to your problem - [R.Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/02/06/10391383.aspx)

Comment: @R.Chen Did you [get that from here?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/02/06/10391383.aspx) :)

Answer (score 24):

Following on the answers here, this prevents the `<br>` tag breaking in both Chrome and IE:

```
br {
    content: " ";
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: But it does not insert any spaces.

Comment: You just put a space in the HTML before or after the <br> tag, right?  So `Foo<br>bar` will look like `Foobar` but `Foo <br>bar` will look like `Foo bar`.  Oddly, `Foo<br> bar` does not preserve the space in IE...

Comment: Yeah, but the OP mentioned, he essentially wants to convert the `<br>` to a space, which your solution does not do. Besides, the `content` property only applies to the `before` and `after` pseudoelements.

Comment: Perhaps it isn't currently possible based on the various comments here.  Whether it is 100% compliant, I can assure you that this CSS is tested in and working cross-browser to prevent the line-break from happening.

Comment: The required solution is to "replace <br /> with space" which this solution unfortunately doesn't do.

Comment: The title of the question is "stop BR tag breaking with CSS" which this solution absolutely does solve for.

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me:

```
br {content: ""}
br:after {content: "\00a0"}
```

Answer (score 8):

Ok, well after some playing around I have found a solution which I'll share with you. It appears it IS possible to control the `<br>` tag fully with CSS

`button br{content:" ";border:1px solid #fff;background:red;padding:50px;}/* whatever you like */`

`button br:after{content:" ";}`

The Html -

`<button>the annoying<br/>tag is gone leaving a controlable space</button>`

Not sure how cross browser this is, but it's working in Webkit and iPhone which for now is all I need.

Comment: +1 Although this isn't cross-browser, it seems to OP is looking for something which works in WebKit browsers so this might be sufficient. In any case, welcome to SO

Answer (score 6):

Why not use:

```
br {
    content: " "; /* Remove break */
    margin-right: 6px; /* Set space between text blocks */
}
```

Comment: So far this is the closest answer to fullfil the requirements if you don't care much about IE

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by boz in the comments on the OP, this isn't going to be possible. Either the `<br/>` is visible (in which case, it's a carriage return) or it's not in which case you have no control over it through CSS.

The fundamental problem here is that you're using the wrong tool for the job - you want to change the structure of the DOM which is the domain of Javascript (in the client at least).

An alternative which doesn't require Javascript or a change to the CMS would be to set up a server to proxy the requests and strip the `<br/>` tags as it passes through the document but it seems like overkill

Answer (score 1):

```
content: " ";
padding-right: 5px; // ok, same as margin-right
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

See [Ignore <br> with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596647/ignore-br-with-css).
One of the solutions is this one (which is the best one in my opinion)

```
br  {
    content: ' '
}
br:after {
    content: ' '
}
```

Comment: Still useful in 2020