# Leading and Trailing <br> removal

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string expression like

```
<br /><br /><br/ >this is <br /><br /><br/ > a test<br /><br /><br/ ><br>
```

in which I need to remove only the first and last set of `<br />` tags using plain javascript.

Comment: Generally, on SO you need to have some kind-of working code that you need help with. SImply asking the community to provide a solution isn't the intention of SO.

Comment: Apologies Frank!.. Would ensure henceforth!

Comment: Please consider choosing the correct answer below. There are already 4 answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If performed globally, this will match all the leading line breaks and all the trailing line breaks (as well as whitespace before/after, let me know if you want to keep the leading/trailing whitespace):

```
^\s*(?:<br\s*\/?\s*>)+|(?:<br\s*\/?\s*>)+\s*$
```

---

Use it like so:

```js
var regex = /^\s*(?:<br\s*\/?\s*>)+|(?:<br\s*\/?\s*>)+\s*$/gi,
    string = '   <br /><br /><br/ >this is <br /><br /><br/ > a test<br /><br /><br/ ><br> ';

string = string.replace(regex, ''); //changed replacement
console.log(string);
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

Comment: I added a `*` quantifier since he wants to remove the leading and trailing `sets` of `<br>` elements. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Php-dev, I misread the question. I improved your edit to have 0+ whitespace after the slash since he has some examples like that.

Comment: Thanks Sam!.. However I want to remove first and last *sets* of <br /> tags, as per your example it removes one <br /> tag both at beginning and end.

Comment: @DavidR, my bad. I have updated. There is one more potential tweak you may want (leading/trailing whitespace is currently being trimmed), let me know :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to process HTML with regexps, which is never a good idea even when it seems innocuous, consider neutralizing the `br` tags with CSS.

```
br { display: none; }
```

See [Ignore <br> with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596647/ignore-br-with-css).

If you want to compress multiple `br` tags, then

```
br + br { display: none; }
```

In your particular case, CSS has no way to detect if the `br`'s appear at the beginning or end of the element. So here's a bit of JavaScript. In general, it's better to manipulate the DOM like this using DOM APIs, instead of mucking around with regexps on the string representation of the DOM:

```
function removeLeadingTrailingBRs(elt) {
    var node;
    while (node=elt.querySelector('br:first-child')) { elt.deleteChild(node); }
    while (node=elt.querySelector('br:last-child'))  { elt.deleteChild(node); }
}
```

Or, if you're a stickler for factoring:

```
function deleteBySelector(elt, selector) {
    var node;
    while (node=elt.querySelector(selector)) { elt.deleteChild(node); }
}
function remoteLeadingTrailingBRs(elt) {
    deleteBySelector('br:first-child');
    deleteBySelector('br:last-child');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
/^\s*<br\s*\/?\s*>|<br\s*\/?\s*>\s*$/ig
```

replace it with empty string:

```
'   <br /><br /><br/ >this is <br /><br /><br/ > a test<br /><br /><br/ ><br> '.replace(/^\s*<br\s*\/?\s*>|<br\s*\/?\s*>\s*$/ig, '')
// => "<br /><br/ >this is <br /><br /><br/ > a test<br /><br /><br/ >"
```

**UPDATE**

To remove multiple occurrence:

```
/^\s*(<br\s*\/?\s*>)+|(<br\s*\/?\s*>)+\s*$/ig
```

---

```
'   <br /><br /><br/ >this is <br /><br /><br/ > a test<br /><br /><br/ ><br> '.replace(/^\s*(<br\s*\/?\s*>)+|(<br\s*\/?\s*>)+\s*$/ig, '')
// => "this is <br /><br /><br/ > a test"
```

Answer (score -4):

I've managed to arrive at solution finally. Below is the RegEx which is working for me.

```
    /^[<br>]*\s*[<br>]*|[<br>]*$/g
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: That regex makes no sense. `[<br>]` matches `<` OR `b` OR `r` OR `>`, not necessarily a `<br>` tag.