# Display data from database without being effected by html tags

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

In my database there is html tags , such as

```
Hello <br/> world
```

And I use the following code in my view to display this data:

```
 <span> @Table.text </span>
```

but the problem is that the data is displayed with break line , it is displayed as
Hello
world

And the same problem happen for any other html tags such as `<a> tag` or `<img> tag`.
In other words, I want to display the data from database as it is without any change.
How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: `@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Table.text))` should help i think

Comment: Quick hack in your css.      span br{display: none}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Html.Raw("Hello <br/> world".Replace("<br/>",""))
```

Comment: I mean for any tag not only <br/> tag.

Comment: So you can clean `<br/>` tags while retrieving from database or you apply [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7596709/492258)

Comment: but I want to display it as (Hellow <br/> world) without being effected by the html codes

Comment: If you have `<br/>` then you have line breaking unless you apply css solution

Comment: what is the css solution ?

Comment: Not that I now write <br/> and it is displayed as <br/> not as line breaking, and that what I want.
br{display:none} not work in this case