# How to display inline text with <br>

Tags: html, css

I have a markup like this:

```
<p>This is first line off text. <br>
   This is second line of text.
</p>
```

I would like to display text inline by adding style="display:inline" like this:

```
<p style="display:inline">This is first line off text. <br>
   This is second line of text.
</p>
```

But it does not work, is there any css method to make it happened?

Many thanks

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Ca2Kvoz.png ???

Comment: you have `<br>` there, so it works as a `<br>`, what do you expect? Remove the br if that's what you mean.

Comment: or use `display: none` on the `<br>` to hide it

Answer (score 1):

You can use display: none on the `<br>` tag. I would set it up conditional on an `inline` class being set on the `<p>` parent tag. [**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/4euwdfee/)

```
p.inline br {
    display: none;
}

<p class="inline">This is first line off text. <br>
   This is second line of text.
</p>
```

*[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7596709/643482)*